# How can I read my mac address from R without a system() call

Tags: macos, r

I need to use the MAC address in a R-script. I want to do without `system()` calls, making it platform independent. Is it possible in R?

Comment: If you put in two-three if statements, you can make it platform independent.

Comment: It may seem trivial, but it's important to use uppercase.  "MAC" is the proper initialism for "media access control."   Meanwhile... how would you propose, in *any* language or shell-like environment, to retrieve a system parameter without a "system call" ?  Pretty much by definition, you can't access the contents of a file without using a system tool.

Comment: I doubt it. Most of the system-dependent functionality that has been wrapped up in a system-independent way is in the `Sys.*` functions, and I don't see one that looks promising for a MAC address.

Answer (score 3):

I'm reasonably sure there's no good way to do this is pure R. However if you're open to dropping into C-land you can implement something [like this example](http://wxwidgets.info/cross-platform-way-of-obtaining-mac-address-of-your-machine/). Where they create a C++ class that detects the OS and then runs the appropriate code to extract the MAC address.

While this may seem very much like using system calls, it's slightly less work than parsing all the [different formats which the command line calls might return the MAC](http://www.coffer.com/mac_info/locate-unix.html).